# Pusher debug console is not showing my events in NodeJS, MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nodejs-server, pusher-js

I am trying to implement a chat functionality using pusher and MongoDB.

I copied the `appId`, `key`, `secret` and `cluster` directly which were generated after creating my app from the pusher.

```
const pusher = new Pusher({
  appId: "correctId which i got",
  key: "correct Key which i got",
  secret: "correct secret",
  cluster: "ap2",
  useTLS: true,
});
```

i live in india so i guess the ap2 cluster is also correct.

here is my trigger request:

```
db.once("open", () => {
  console.log("db is connected");

  const msgCollection = db.collection("messagecontents");
  const changeStream = msgCollection.watch();

  changeStream.on("change", (change) => {
    console.log("a change occured", change);

    if (change.operationType === "insert") {
      const messageDetails = change.fullDocument;
      pusher.trigger("messages", "inserted", {
        name: messageDetails.name,
        message: messageDetails.message,
      });
    } else {
      console.log("error triggering pusher");
    }
  });
});
```

My console log is showing the changes correctly but my Pusher debug console is not showing anything:

[my debug console screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qn2F.jpg)

Thanks for any kind of help in advance